# What does $ \chi(Tree)\leq 2 $ mean in graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I am reading an article about graphs in English. Does $\chi(Tree)\leq 2$ mean that each node has no more then $2$ children?

Comment: Perhaps $\chi$ means the Euler characteristic of the graph?

Comment: Let me also add that the quantity you mentioned is called the **branching factor**, and is sometimes denoted $b$ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_factor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let G be a graph. The symbol $\chi(G)$ usually denotes the **chromatic number** of G, that is, the minimum number of colors required to color the vertices of G in such a way that no two adjacent vertices share the same color.

It's easy to see that, if G is a tree, then it can be colored with at most two colors, therefore $\chi(\text{Tree}) \le 2$.